# Writing a listner to Azure Queue

Tags: azure, azure-queues

I have seen most queue example as the polling mechanism . Is it possible to change it to listner of the queue. Because polling may affect the performance of the worker.

Comment: "Because polling may affect the performance of the worker" - Really? How often do you plan on polling? Can you share more about the performance problems you've run into?

Comment: @smarx will it not affect the performance because we are using the resources unnecessary . but your question is valid i will do a performance run on that . But to be noted we are making a http call with the queue.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Both Windows Azure Storage Queues and Windows Azure Service Bus Queues utilize polling and do not have a notification feature per se; however, Windows Azure Service Bus Queues do support long polling which is as close to a notification approach as you can get currently.  When you use the Receive method from MessageReceiver it will use long polling (meaning it will request a message and if there isn't one in the queue the server won't immediately respond, but will wait a period of time until either a message comes into the queue when it will respond to the client, or until an idle time passes in which case it will return a response with no message.  The Receive method by itself will give the impression of a synchronous call to get a message and will not return until a message appears, but it has overloads to allow for idle times so you don't get into an infinite wait).

In Service Bus Topics you can set up as a subscriber, but you will still be polling the topic to get your messages, so I don't think that is at the heart of what the OP is asking.

Comment: But it will be good if we have listner. Any idea if this availble in MS connect .else i can add a connect bug

Comment: I'm not aware of a request for a full on notification feature currently.

Answer (score 3):

Using Windows Azure Queue, your only option is polling. While with the [Service Bus Topics/Subscription](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh367516.aspx), you can have full pub/sub model, where your subscriber will be a "listener".

Comment: But you will still be polling the topic on a Service Bus Topic to retrieve your messages.  The subscription model simply lets you have multiple destinations for an inbound queue message, plus filtering; however, in the end, the listeners (or consumers) will still be polling their respective topics for their messages.