# Subscribing to an Azure Queue

Tags: c#, azure-worker-roles, azureservicebus, azure-queues, azure-servicebus-queues

I have an Azure web site that generates reports.  The reports take ~45 seconds to generate and I'd like to migrate that a worker role to lessen the load on the web site.

I've been researching which tool to use to enable the web site to pass a "report generation request" to the worker role.  [Azure Queues](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-queues/) look like the way to go, but from what I've seen in the [Channel 9 Azure Friday  series](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Azure-Friday/Azure-Queues-101-Basics-of-Queues-with-Mark-Simms), [blog posts](http://blog.cloudish.net/windows-azure-storage-queues-polling/) and Stackoverflow ([Azure Service bus queues topics vs queues for web/worker roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183326/azure-service-bus-queues-topics-vs-queues-for-web-worker-roles), [Writing a listner to Azure Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737360/writing-a-listner-to-azure-queue)), **Azure Queue only supports polling**.

However, Azure is changing rapidly and this information is a bit old.  Is it still the case that Queue's only support polling?

If that's the case would I be better off using Azure Service Bus to pass messages as it supports a Publish/Subscribe model?  I'm a little hesitant to use the Service Bus as I don't seam to need any of the features specific to the Service Bus descibed on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh767287%28VS.103%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're looking for a publish/subscribe messaging pattern, check out Service Bus topics and subscriptions (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh367516.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699844.aspx). Topics and subscriptions are basically Service Bus queues with pub/sub capabilities.

For more background information, you might want to check out this comparison of Azure Queues and Service Bus queues: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh767287.aspx.

Hope that information helps,
Seth Manheim
Azure Doc Team

Comment: I looked at the pub/sub links and maybe I'm using the wrong terminology.  Perhaps the right term is "event driven".  I found this article documenting events in Service Bus (http://fabriccontroller.net/blog/posts/introducing-the-event-driven-message-programming-model-for-the-windows-azure-service-bus/).  Azure Queues doesn't support this do they?

Comment: If you want event driven, use Event Hub: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/event-hubs/

Answer (score 3):

I believe Azure Queues still only support polling. I can't find any documentation that says otherwise. If you want a publish / subscribe model, Service Bus Queues or Event Hubs may work best for you.

Comment: If Azure Queues doesn't support polling, then what would the primary use case for them be?  It's seems it would be quite expensive to pay for CPU time to constantly poll a queue if there wasn't a very large work load (ie only say 30 messages an hour)

Comment: The main thing I can think of is cost. Azure Queues cost $0.0005 per 10,000 transactions, but also have a storage cost of $0.07 per GB/month. SB queues cost $0.01 per 10,000 messages with no storage cost.

Answer (score 1):

"Azure Storage Queues implements the publish/subscribe (pub/sub) pattern. In version 9 and below, this feature relies on message-driven pub/sub which requires a separate persistence for storage of subscription information. In version 10 and above, the transport handles subscription information natively and a separate persistence is not required."
https://docs.particular.net/transports/azure-storage-queues/native-publish-subscribe

[image: Adding trigger to workflow]